# Restservice - Method Put with a for each option

Tags: powershell, foreach, put

Im trying to make a powershell script that get a json file from on point and puts in in an other. The getting part is done. I have a code something like this:

```
*$sourceFolder = 'my folder'
$token = 'my token'
$encodedToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
$authValue = "AfasToken $encodedToken"
$Headers = @{
Authorization = $authValue
}
  $url = "https://my.url.nl/Restservices/budgethouders?skip=0&take=1000"
$file = 'my file'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $file -Headers $Headers*
```

This works and ik get a file. Like this:

```
{ "skip" : 0,
  "take" : 1000,
  "rows" : [
  {
    "CmId": "1",
    "CrId": 100,
    "CrDs": "Directie",
    "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
    "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
    "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
  },
  {
    "CmId": "1",
    "CrId": 101,
    "CrDs": "Dimensie",
    "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
    "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
    "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
  }
]}
```

Now i would like to use the file i have to return it to the service in a code that get the info out of the file i just saved. I know how i kan make the code manualy. But i can not seem te get te for each state ment right. My own code that works looks like this:

```
$sourceFolder = 'my folder'


$token = 'my token'
$encodedToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
$authValue = "AfasToken $encodedToken"
$Headers = @{
Authorization = $authValue
}


    $url = "https://my.url.nl/Restservices/connectors/CostCentre"
    $file = '{
  "HrCostCentre": {
    "Element": {
      "Fields": {
        "CmId": "1",
        "CrId": "100",
        "CrDs": "Directie",
        "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
        "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
        "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
      }
    }
  }
}'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Method PUT -Headers $Headers -Body $file
    $url = "https://my.url.nl/Restservices/connectors/HrCostCentre"
    $file = '{
  "HrCostCentre": {
    "Element": {
      "Fields": {
        "CmId": "1",
        "CrId": 101,
        "CrDs": "Dimensie",
        "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
        "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
        "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
  }
    }
  }
}'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Method PUT -Headers $Headers -Body $file
```

This works but I would luke to use the info from My file in the update but dont know how te get the code right. I realy am a beginner so i am happy i already got this far. I would aprciate al the help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

This will properly work for you:

```
$budgethouders = ConvertFrom-JSON '
{ "skip" : 0,
  "take" : 1000,
  "rows" : [
  {
    "CmId": "1",
    "CrId": 100,
    "CrDs": "Directie",
    "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
    "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
    "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
  },
  {
    "CmId": "1",
    "CrId": 101,
    "CrDs": "Dimensie",
    "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD": "506",
    "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E": "11186",
    "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554": "11186"
  }
]}
'

$file = ConvertTo-JSON @{
    "HrCostCentre" = @{
        "Element" = @{
            "Fields" = New-Object PSObject $budgethouders.rows[0] # or .rows[1]
        }
    }
}
```

But it leads to a new question: *where does the* `"value":  ""` *in the result come from?* (I have not found an easy solution yet to logically suppress this):

```
{
    "HrCostCentre":  {
                         "Element":  {
                                         "Fields":  {
                                                        "value":  "",
                                                        "CmId":  "1",
                                                        "CrId":  100,
                                                        "CrDs":  "Directie",
                                                        "U266FAB0A4D908F09592CD7A18E24B1DD":  "506",
                                                        "U624D2D6B4FFA8407904125BBCB35A80E":  "11186",
                                                        "U7A831591420B12B7871EFF8C4AB4E554":  "11186"
                                                    }
                                     }
                     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow with your comment i figured it out. Not the most bueatifull code but it works :)

I get the file and eddit it to a script that works, thanks for your input.

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\my folder\'


$token = 'my token'
$encodedToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
$authValue = "AfasToken $encodedToken"
$Headers = @{
Authorization = $authValue
}

  $url = "https://My.url.nl/Restservices/connectors/budgethouders?skip=0&take=1"

$file = $Sourcefolder + 'Budgethouders.json'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $file -Headers $Headers


$Budgethouders = $file
(Get-Content $Budgethouders| Select-Object -Skip 3) |Select -SkipLast 1| Set-Content $Budgethouders

$Orgineel1 = "{"
$Orgineel2 = "},"
$Dollar = "$"
$Url = "url = "
$link = [char]34 + "https://my.url.nl/Restservices/connectors/HrCostCentre"+ [char]34
$enter = "
"
$F = "File ="
$haakjeopen = "'{"
$tekst1 = [char]34 + "HrCostCentre" + [char]34 +": {"
$tekst2 = [char]34 + "Element" +[char]34 + ": {"
$tekst3 = [char]34 + "Fields" + [char]34 + ": {"
$Sluiten =  "}
    }
  }
}'
"
$sluiten2 ="}
  }
}'
"
$invoke1 = "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri " + $dollar + "url -ContentType application/json -Method PUT -Headers "+ $dollar +"Headers -Body " + $dollar + "file"
$vervang1 = $Dollar+ $Url+ $link + $enter + $dollar + $F + $haakjeopen + $enter + $tekst1 + $enter + $tekst2 + $enter + $tekst3
$vervang2 = $Sluiten + $enter + $invoke1
$invoketotaal = $invoke1



(Get-Content $Budgethouders) -replace $Orgineel1,$vervang1 | out-file $Budgethouders 
(Get-Content $Budgethouders) -replace $Orgineel2,$vervang2| out-file $Budgethouders
Add-Content $Budgethouders $sluiten2 
Add-Content $Budgethouders $enter
Add-Content $Budgethouders $invoketotaal


$Jsonfile = $file
$tekstfile = $sourcefolder + "Temp text file.txt"
$tempfile = $sourcefolder +"auto.txt"
$scriptfile = $sourcefolder + "script.ps1"

Add-Content -Path $tempfile -Value (Get-Content $tekstfile) 



Add-Content -Path $tempfile -Value (Get-Content $Jsonfile)


(Get-Content $tempfile) | Out-File $scriptfile

Invoke-Expression $Scriptfile

Remove-Item $Scriptfile
Remove-item $tempfile
remove-item $jsonfile
```